# Divide by 0 Error Inside Windows Function

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to calculate the % of closed claims divided by total claims per month using Windows functions.  But some months will have zero total claims which results in the `Divide by zero error encountered` message.

I have tried writing a CASE statement to handle where the total claims equal zero to be set the percentage to zero but I have not had any luck so far.

Below is a screenshot of what I am expecting:

[image]

And the TSQL below are my attempts at error handling the divide by zero message: I've added a NULLIF on the bottom of the divider and an attempt at a CASE statement to set the value = 0 when the bottom divider is zero - both result in the same error.  Any suggestions on how to get around this error?

```
CREATE TABLE #ClaimCounts
(
Year INT,
ClaimStatus VARCHAR (50),
LossMonth DATE,
ClaimMonth DATE,
ClaimCount INT
);

INSERT INTO #ClaimCounts
(
Year,
ClaimStatus,
LossMonth,
ClaimMonth,
ClaimCount
)
VALUES
(2008, 'Closed', '20080630', '20080131', 0),
(2008, 'Total', '20080630', '20080131', 0),
(2008, 'Closed', '20080630', '20080229', 0),
(2008, 'Total', '20080630', '20080229', 0),
(2008, 'Closed', '20080630', '20080331', 0),
(2008, 'Total', '20080630', '20080331', 0),
(2008, 'Closed', '20080630', '20080430', 0),
(2008, 'Total', '20080630', '20080430', 0),
(2008, 'Closed', '20080630', '20080531', 0),
(2008, 'Total', '20080630', '20080531', 0),
(2008, 'Closed', '20080630', '20080630', 0),
(2008, 'Total', '20080630', '20080630', 6),
(2008, 'Closed', '20080630', '20090731', 2),
(2008, 'Total', '20080630', '20090731', 5),
(2008, 'Closed', '20080630', '20080831', 1),
(2008, 'Total', '20080630', '20080831', 1),
(2008, 'Closed', '200806308', '20080930', 3),
(2008, 'Total', '20080630', '20080930', 3),
(2008, 'Closed', '20080630', '20081031', 2),
(2008, 'Total', '20080630', '20081031', 3),
(2008, 'Closed', '200806308', '20081130', 0),
(2008, 'Total', '20080630', '20081130', 0);

SELECT Year,
   ClaimStatus,
   LossMonth,
   ClaimMonth,
   ClaimCount,
   SUM ( CASE WHEN ClaimStatus = 'Closed' THEN ISNULL ( ClaimCount, 0 ) * 1.0 ELSE 0 END ) OVER (PARTITION BY Year, ClaimMonth) / 
   SUM ( CASE WHEN ClaimStatus = 'Total' THEN ClaimCount * 1.0 ELSE 0 END ) OVER (PARTITION BY Year, ClaimMonth) AS PercentageClosedClaims1 ,

   SUM ( CASE WHEN ClaimStatus = 'Closed' THEN ISNULL ( ClaimCount, 0 ) * 1.0 ELSE 0 END ) OVER (PARTITION BY Year, ClaimMonth) / 
   SUM ( CASE WHEN ClaimStatus = 'Total' THEN NULLIF(ClaimCount, 0) * 1.0 ELSE 0 END ) OVER (PARTITION BY Year, ClaimMonth) AS PercentageClosedClaims2 ,

   CASE WHEN ClaimStatus = 'Total' AND ClaimCount = 0 THEN 0
       ELSE SUM ( CASE WHEN ClaimStatus = 'Closed' THEN ISNULL ( ClaimCount, 0 ) * 1.0 ELSE 0 END ) OVER (PARTITION BY Year, ClaimMonth) / 
            SUM ( CASE WHEN ClaimStatus = 'Total' THEN ISNULL ( ClaimCount, 0 ) * 1.0 ELSE 0 END ) OVER (PARTITION BY Year, ClaimMonth)
   END AS PercentageClosedClaims3
FROM #ClaimCounts;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ClaimCounts;
```

Comment: IsNull( YourNumerator / NullIf(YourDenominator,0) , 0 )

Comment: DDL and DML is great, but please try to avoid language specific dates. For most of the world there aren't 30 months in the year. :) The ISO formats `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn` are always preferred, as then people don't need to change their language settings or modify your data so it's consumable. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu - I have updated the TSQL.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti - I'm not sure how I can apply your answer to my code.

Comment: @MISNole See answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working option.  The `IsNull()` is optional.  I personally don't mind `NULL` values.

```
SELECT Year
      ,ClaimStatus
      ,LossMonth
      ,ClaimMonth
      ,ClaimCount
      ,PercentageClosedClaims1 = IsNull(SUM ( CASE WHEN ClaimStatus = 'Closed' THEN ISNULL ( ClaimCount, 0 ) * 1.0 ELSE 0 END ) OVER (PARTITION BY Year, ClaimMonth) 
                                        / nullif(SUM ( CASE WHEN ClaimStatus = 'Total' THEN ClaimCount * 1.0 ELSE 0 END ) OVER (PARTITION BY Year, ClaimMonth),0) 
                                        ,0)
      ,PercentageClosedClaims2 = IsNull(SUM ( CASE WHEN ClaimStatus = 'Closed' THEN ISNULL ( ClaimCount, 0 ) * 1.0 ELSE 0 END ) OVER (PARTITION BY Year, ClaimMonth) 
                                        / nullif(SUM ( CASE WHEN ClaimStatus = 'Total' THEN NULLIF(ClaimCount, 0) * 1.0 ELSE 0 END ) OVER (PARTITION BY Year, ClaimMonth),0) 
                                        ,0)
      ,PercentageClosedClaims3 = IsNull(SUM ( CASE WHEN ClaimStatus = 'Closed' THEN ISNULL ( ClaimCount, 0 ) * 1.0 ELSE 0 END ) OVER (PARTITION BY Year, ClaimMonth) 
                                        / nullif(SUM ( CASE WHEN ClaimStatus = 'Total' THEN ISNULL ( ClaimCount, 0 ) * 1.0 ELSE 0 END ) OVER (PARTITION BY Year, ClaimMonth),0)
                                        ,0)

FROM #ClaimCounts;
```

Comment: Thanks John for the answer! And for reminding me of the terms Numerator & Denominator - I had totally forgotten those terms.